# Instruct a relationship between many Users and many Companies in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I’m working on a project where I got confused on how to structure it models, and I appreciate your inputs in order to understand how to grow about the best solution fits projects requirements.

**Requirements**

After a user signup it would be able to complete is profile (users has_on :profile).   That profile would be available to public to review as profile to resume, regardless user is looking for a job or one a company. 
All users should be able to create one or more than one company (users has_many :companies, through: :roles) and companies would belongs to many users (companies has_mamy :users , through: :roles).

Here are my models and migrations:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through: :roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :roles
  has_many :companies, through: :roles
end


class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string    :name, limit: 255, null: false
      t.text      :description, limit: 1500, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.references :company, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :roles, [:user_id, :company_id]
  end
end
```

And User is done by Devise.

I have tried `has_many_and_belongs_to` association, but I found it is limitation since I would need to interact with Role model later on. As you see I would have different Uses, ‘**Employee**’, ‘**Job Seekers**’, ‘**Founders**’, ‘**Investors**’, ….etc and other interactions.

Job seekers would be able to create Notes, Blog posts, and News **but NOT** create a job post or Marketing Campaign. While Founders would do everything.

I’m having problem with the following:

- Am I using the right associations? I know naming table is important, does Role fits the requirements?
- How to construct Companies, Users, and Roles controllers and views.

I want to show:

- All Companies from all users.
- Companies from specific User (Employees/ investors/ founders)
- All Founders profile.(either user show method or a separate profile model)
- All Investors.
- All job seekers.

**UPDATE**

`companies_controller.rb`
Where I'm having problem with retrieving `users companies` and `companies users or user`.

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: %i[new create edit update destroy]
  before_action :assign_company, except: %i[new create index]

  def index
    @companies = Company.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @company = current_user.companies.build
  end

  def create
    @company = current_user.companies.build(company_params)
    if @company.save
      redirect_to company_path(@company), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    return redirect_to company_path if current_user.id == @company.user.id
    render :edit
  end

  def update
    @company.update(company_params)
    return redirect_to company_path(@company) if @company.save
    render :edit
  end


  def destroy
    @company.destroy
    redirect_to companies_path, notice: 'Company was successfully destroyed.'
  end


  private
    def assign_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end

    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :description, :roles)
    end
end
```

I feel it is an easy to accomplish and I feel I over complicated it. Am I?
I would appreciate your input and helping me on understanding the best work fellow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The name `Role` seems fine IMO. Maybe you should add a string column like `role_type` so that a `role` with `role_type = 'founder'` is actually a `Founder` of the associated `Company`.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Is the association i have correct? How I would go about doing it's controller?

Comment: The association is correct. You might want to have different plain-old-ruby-objects (or CanCan Ability subclasses) to define each role's type ACL. About the controller, you would not need a `RolesController` since the Role is the record defining the relation type between a User and a Company. So when adding a Founder to a Company, it would be `company.founders.create!(user_id: current_user.id)` where `Company#founders` is defined as `Company` `has_many :founders, ->{ where(role_type: :founder) }, class_name: 'User'`

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji I will consider CanCan Ability for sure. I'm at a point when 'current_user' can create a company. But when I do `users.companies` I got nothing, same with `companies.users`.  I update my Q with CompaniesController.